# Pre-insert/update trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

All we need is to create several pre-insert/update triggers in SQL Server 2008 R2 which do some `select *` or `select count(*)` and explicitly fail if it is empty or non-empty.

Please, how to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a trigger instead of in the INSERT/UPDATE statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE` trigger. Now to prevent DML you have 2 options. In the body of trigger execute `RAISERROR` so your application can catch the error. Another way is not to perform actual `insert/update` in the trigger, so no records will be inserted/updated, but the user will not know if DML succeeds.